# my props.children are not rendering, but they are in the parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here is my main App class:

```
return(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <View style={ { flex: 1, paddingTop: paddingTop } }>
      <MainScreenNavigator/>
    </View>
  </Provider>
)
```

which works. But if I try to wrap this in a Login like this:

```
return(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <View style={ { flex: 1, paddingTop: paddingTop } }>
      <Login>
        <MainScreenNavigator/>
      </Login>
    </View>
  </Provider>
)
```

with the Login class as follows:

```
class Login extends Component {
  render = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Nothing gets rendered. I don't understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `View` in `Login` does not have dimensions. Give it a style of `flex: 1` and you should see your `this.props.children`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Login extends Component {
  render = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: Also this answer was already given by Mμ.